# TSQL query to return values from a table where there are multiple rows with same ID into a single row but each unique value in a different column

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to return values from a table so that I get 1 row per purchaseID and return multiple columns with Buyers First and Last Names.

E.G
I have a table with the following Data

**|  PurchaseID | FirstName | LastName|**
|---------1------- | ----Joe------ | ---Smith----|
|---------1------- | -----Peter--- | ---Pan------|
|---------2------- | ----Max------|---Power----|
|---------2------- | -----Jack---- | ---Frost----|

I'm trying to write a query that returns the values like so

**| PurchaseID | Buyer1FirstName | Buyer1LastName | Buyer2FirstName |Buyer2LastName|**
|--------1---------|------------Joe--------- |--------Smith----------|---------Peter-----------|--------Pan------------|
 |--------2---------|-------------Max--------|---------Power--------|---------Jack -----------|---------Frost----------|

I've been looking online but because I'm not sure how to explain in words what I want to do, I'm not having much luck. I'm hoping with a more visual explanation someone could point me in the right direction.

Any help would be awesome.

Comment: Is the number of columns that you want to produce thoroughly unpredictable? Do you want a different number of columns for each row depending on the number of buyers for the corresponding product? Why would you want to do this in the database?

Comment: The maximum number of buyers would be 4 so for any row where there is less than 4 buyers, those columns would be null. The purpose is to create a datasource for a mail merge / document merge where the results need to be 1 to 1. so each row would be a purchase record that we could use to insert into a settlement document etc. I've already created the view for the rest of the content. Its only the buyer names I'm having issue with.

Comment: Since you are doing this for the purposes of formatting a settlement document it would be appropriate to handle this in the application code that generates the document. This sort of formatting is, as a rule, better handled in the application instead of the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER` as the below:

```
DECLARE @Tbl TABLE (PurchaseID INT, FirstName  VARCHAR(50), LastName VARCHAR(50))
INSERT INTO @Tbl        
VALUES  
(1, 'Joe', 'Smith'),
(1, 'Peter', 'Pan'),
(2, 'Max', 'Power'),
(2, 'Jack', 'Frost'),
(2, 'Opss', 'Sspo')


;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
        *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PurchaseID ORDER BY PurchaseID) RowId
    FROM @Tbl
)

SELECT
    A.PurchaseID,
    MIN(CASE WHEN A.RowId = 1 THEN A.FirstName END) Buyer1FirstName,
    MIN(CASE WHEN A.RowId = 1 THEN A.LastName END ) Buyer1LastName ,
    MIN(CASE WHEN A.RowId = 2 THEN A.FirstName END) Buyer2FirstName ,
    MIN(CASE WHEN A.RowId = 2 THEN A.LastName END )Buyer2LastName,
    MIN(CASE WHEN A.RowId = 3 THEN A.FirstName END) Buyer3FirstName ,
    MIN(CASE WHEN A.RowId = 3 THEN A.LastName END )Buyer3LastName,
    MIN(CASE WHEN A.RowId = 4 THEN A.FirstName END) Buyer4FirstName ,
    MIN(CASE WHEN A.RowId = 4 THEN A.LastName END )Buyer4LastName   
FROM
    CTE A
GROUP BY
    A.PurchaseID
```

Result:

```
PurchaseID  Buyer1FirstName     Buyer1LastName       Buyer2FirstName      Buyer2LastName     Buyer3FirstName     Buyer3LastName    Buyer4FirstName     Buyer4LastName
----------- ------------------- -------------------- -------------------- ------------------ ------------------- ----------------- ------------------- --------------
1           Joe                 Smith                Peter                Pan                NULL                NULL              NULL                NULL
2           Max                 Power                Jack                 Frost              Opss                Sspo              NULL                NULL
```

Comment: Thanks NEER! That is exactly what I needed. Much Appreciated.